logger crashed when selenium not found element by xpath
So, this code crushed when web driver not found element:
try:
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'some_text')]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
except Exception as e:
   logger.exception('Error into get_time_sale(), no such element')

and this code crushed with the same exception "no such element". Logger also not work and "try except" too:
try:
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'some_text')]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
except Exception as e:
  logger.error(f'Error into get_time_sale(), no such element: {e}')

this code work and logger too:
try:
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'some_text')]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
except Exception as e:
   logger.error('Error into get_time_sale(), no such element')

Just want share this situation, maybe who else try to fix this! My Python version 3.12(gpt)

What does this exception catch?

No such element.

Now that the exception is caught, this code will not go wrong unless there is another exception in your exception.

I tried to catch exception inside except, but it doesn't work.

try：
try: import traceback    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'some_text')]").get_attribute('innerHTML') except Exception as e:    print(str(e))    print(traceback.format_exc())

I still can't see your abnormal information
